Does anyone know of the chromium command switch to hide the "free up space to continue" prompt?
I am currently trying to debug a chrome kiosk application, it's very simplistic but these annoying popups appear after every reboot saying that I must Free up space to continue, and that "Some features on (website) might not work until you clear data...". I understand that it isn't ideal to just hide the warning, but the prompt keeps covering up some useful information and an associated chromium command line switch would provide an ideal temporary solution.
I've searched through the list on this source: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ but unfortunately I haven't found any that appear to work other than the usual "--disable-infobars" and "--kiosk" and "noerrdialogs", etc.
If anybody knows of the actual switch that controls the suppression of this warning it would be super helpful (assuming it exists haha)

Carmen

